# Batch vs BPMN processing with long wait states

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, camunda

I am working on a Java project (Spring) where I need to create batch processing for a rather complex scenario. Some of the steps would have to do a rather long waiting, e.g. 20 days. I am not really sure, how I should tackle this scenario.

My first thought was to do it in a BPMN engine (like Camunda), where wait states are part of the modelling elements. Taking in consideration the amount of data that need to be processed, I would end up with around 250.000 process instances for a single run and this amount of data concerns from a performance perspective in case of a BPMN-based processing.

The other solution would be taking a framework designed for batch processing, e.g. Spring Batch. My problem in that case is the long wait states. As far as I understood it, Spring Batch doesn't support wait states. Each draft solution I came up with however, has some limitation.

Would I do it in one big batch, the step, where potentially the wait can occur, will halt until the 20 days are over. This would block processing the rest of the data to be processed. I guess I could mark the given data item to be processed later, and re-run the batch until every item is processed. This would mean I would need to lay out every branch of the processing in a linear fashion and the steps themselves would accept only data items marked for them.

Would I start a new batch job for every item to be processed, I would need a mechanism to stop at a given point and then later revive the job/step from a given step. A natural solution would be to create a more fine grained job system but then I would lose the context information about the processing.

In both cases, I would end up with my own BPMN solution implemented as a state machine in the database...

I would appreciate any help or hint you can give me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discussed this issue also with my technical lead and there were several arguments against BPMN (Camunda).

1. level of difficulty of a potential process update in case there are instances still in wait state (e.g. running processes).
2. using BPMN and potentially solving scaling and performance could be in contradiction for what we originally intended to use it (simple message orchestration).

Because of these reasons the decision was to go with Spring Batch, where we divide the business batch (as described in the activity diagrams, with the wait states etc.) and the technical batch (the Spring Batch implementation). In that case, every step can take the current context, perform the operation and update it. One technical batch would potentially handle every business batch currently planned to be processed (e.g. data of the newly created batch and all those where the wait states expired today). This also require us to create a state machine; probably one which supports parallel execution as well (for example Petri net).

Comment: I am afraid I would disagree with both points. A process engine usually has multi-version enactment. Camunda specifically has API and graphical tooling, which offers process migration between versions, and easy modification of data and STATE. 
The scalability issue may apply to some BPMS. Camunda Platfom runs millions of processes a day, Camunda Cloud / Zeebe can run magnitudes higher with almost linear scalability - both engines use BPMN.

Answer (score 3):

Approaching it with BPM gives you transparency, flexibility, faster implementation, and out of the box persistence and error handling, and most importantly support for long-running processes. I don't share the performance concern. 250,000 (daily? Monthly or every 20 days?) is not much for Camunda. You write process instances may run for about 20 days, but I don't see how frequently you start these jobs of 250,000. If it is a business daily run, you would still only end up with 5,500,000 instances per month. Not an issue. You should consider

- what history level you need. Likely full is not required here,audit may be sufficient.
- how big the batch items are and where they will be stored. It is not a good design to persist large business objects as process data. A simple CRUD service for the business object would be better. You can work with transient process data when accessing them from the engine. (OK... if the object are not big and we are only talking 250k instance a month, even simple JSON serialization as process data may do.)
- how long you want to store the audit data? Set the TTL on the process accordingly. Seem like <30 days could be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 250.000 is a weekly number.  Your assumptions were correct in the sense, that our context is fully stored in the database, the process instances themselves would not contain much information, only the bare minimum. Audit data is handled in a separate service which will be pinged during processing.